# Create Google Calendar invites using service account securely

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-calendar-api, google-api-python-client, service-accounts

I created a service account using my Enterprise Google Workspace account and I need to automate calendar invites creation using Python.

I have added the service account email into the calendar's shared people and when I try to get the calendar using `service.calendarList().list().execute()` it works fine.

However, if I try to send an invite it doesn't work, and I get the error below:

`googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/xxxxxx%group.calendar.google.com/events?alt=json returned "You need to have writer access to this calendar.". Details: "[{'domain': 'calendar', 'reason': 'requiredAccessLevel', 'message': 'You need to have writer access to this calendar.'}]">`

Looking at the [docs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#delegatingauthority) I found that I need to delegate domain-wide authority to the service account for this to work, but my company isn't allowing this service account to have this type of access because of security issues.

So I wanted to know if there is any way that I could do this without delegating domain wide access to this service account ? Because delegating domain wide access gives me access to impersonated anyone in the domain, so it's a security issue. I want the service account to be able to impersonate just the parent google account from where it was created.

Below is the full code that I used to get the calendar and create the invite

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from googleapiclient.discovery import build


class GoogleCalendar:
    SCOPES = [
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events",
    ]

    def __init__(self, credentials, calendar_id) -> None:
        credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
            credentials, scopes=self.SCOPES
        )
        self.service = build("calendar", "v3", credentials=credentials)
        self.id = calendar_id

    def get_calendar_list(self):
        return self.service.calendarList().list().execute()

    def add_calendar(self):
        entry = {"id": self.id}
        return self.service.calendarList().insert(body=entry).execute()

    def create_invite(self):
        event = {
            "summary": "Google I/O 2015",
            "location": "800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103",
            "description": "A chance to hear more about Google's developer products.",
            "start": {
                "dateTime": "2023-09-16T09:00:00-07:00",
                "timeZone": "America/Los_Angeles",
            },
            "end": {
                "dateTime": "2023-09-16T17:00:00-07:00",
                "timeZone": "Indian/Mauritius",
            },
            "attendees": [{"email": "myemail@domain.com"}],
        }

        event = self.service.events().insert(calendarId=self.id, body=event).execute()

work_cal_id = "xxxxx@group.calendar.google.com"

cal = GoogleCalendar(
credentials="work.json", 
calendar_id=work_cal_id
)

cal.add_calendar()

print(cal.get_calendar_list())

cal.create_invite()
```

Comment: can I see the code you use to authorize this call?

Comment: Why did you choose to use a service account if domain-wide is not an option? Domain-wide app/daemon-level access is the main scenario for the service accounts. It sounds like you simply need a regular oauth2 flow to get a user based authorization.

Comment: I chose service account because it is going to run on a server without human interaction. With oauth, there is a manual part where we need to choose the google account. A script running on a server can't do that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK you have 2 options available to you. Google has removed several other options.

1. **Serviceaccount with delegation.** *You state that this is not an option for you, but technically it is.*
2. **Give serviceaccount access to Calendar API for specific user, using OAuth 2.0**.

---

### Option 1

This is actually the best *(and the "proper" way)*, but I can understand the security problems that this option entails, as delegation can be a very big security risk if the SA gets compromised.

---

### Option 2

This is currently the only other option. See [this article](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2) for OAuth 2.0 details.

It's basically the implementation of giving an app access to Google API endpoints for a user.

This picture does a nice recap:
[image]

The user in the picture above should be an existing user in your company that has edit access to the calendar in question. You might want to create a specific user for this (such as `calendar@domain.com` or `no-reply@domain.com`), to not tie the invitations to a specific "real" user.

Basically the only thing that changes compared to your existing code is the generation of the token/credentials. [This article](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#obtainingaccesstokens) explains how to create the credentials object you need to authenticate the requests.

Whether or not this works for you depends on the security requirements for your company, and the specific Workspace settings applied to the workspace account.

The [article linked above for OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2) is a very good starting point, followed by the [specific article for server-side apps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZFU1.png).

---

Please do take token expiration into account. Not using the refresh token for 6 months fe. will invalidate it...

Comment: Very nicely explained. Thanks a lot

Answer (score -1):

The first thing i would check is that you have the corect scope events.insert requires either

- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events

After that I would check that you have properly delegated to a user on the domain. This is done by calling `create_delegated` with that users domain email address.

Then I would check to ensure that that user has access to what ever calendar `calendarId=self.id` is.

```
def create_calendar_service(user_email):
    """Build and return a calendar service object authorized with the service
  account that acts on behalf of the given user.

  Args:
    user_email: The email of the user to impersonate. Needs permissions to access Cloud Search.
  Returns:
    calendar API service object that is ready to make requests.
  """

    credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
        SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE_PATH,
        scopes=SCOPES)

    credentials = credentials.create_delegated(user_email)

    return build("calendar", "v3", credentials=credentials)
```

## error from comments

> Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method, or client not authorized for any of the scopes requested.

Okay this error can mean a few things.

First off check your credential.json file make sure it starts with `"type": "service_account"` if it doesn't then you created the wrong credential type.

Second make sure that your code has include `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar` it need that scope to do a create.

Third check that you have properly configured domain wide delegation and included https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar scope in the permissions.

Comment: Hi @Linda Lawton, I added the full code. The service account has access, as I added it as "Make changes and manage sharing" to the calendar. Also, if I try to use `credentials = credentials.create_delegated(user_email)`, I am getting the error `'Credentials' object has no attribute 'create_delegated'` because i am using `service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file` method.

Comment: Sp i tried to use `credentials = credentials.with_subject(email)` instead and i get the error `{'error': 'unauthorized_client', 'error_description': 'Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method, or client not authorized for any of the scopes requested.'}`

Comment: I dont think you are using a service account.

Comment: I think i am. I definitely created a service account from GCP. Can you please explain what i am doing wrong ?

Comment: Check my update that error can mean a few things.